# Updating rows in a view from a complex select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been working on a query that identifies an issue with the data in my database:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM [DailyTaskHours] t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ActivityDate
        ,taskId
        ,EnteredBy
    FROM [DailyTaskHours]
    WHERE hours != 0
    GROUP BY EnteredBy
        ,taskId
        ,ActivityDate
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) t2 ON (
        t1.ActivityDate = t2.ActivityDate
        AND t1.taskId = t2.taskId
        AND t1.EnteredBy = t2.EnteredBy
        AND t1.Hours != 0
        )
ORDER BY ActivityDate
```

What this does is find duplicate hours booked for the same person on the same task on the same day:

[image]

Now that I found the issues I want to correct them with an UPDATE. I want the duplicate activity that was created earlier than the other to move the value from Hours to doubleBookedHours and for Hours to be zeroed out. Secondly, I want the more recent row's DoubleBookedFLag column to be updated to 1.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a SQL Server Agent Job to call T-SQL or a SSIS package to perform your logic.

I always like using pseudo code when designing my algorithm.

For instance.

1. Find duplicate entries and save them to a temporary table, either in a staging area or tempdb.  Some location that is accessible by multiple processes (spids).
2. Find least recent records (1+).  Move hours to double booked column?
3. Find least recent records (1+).  Zero out hours column.
4. Update the most recent record to have double book flag column set to 1.

You were not specific on moving the value from hours to double booked hours. Are these columns?

In short, a SQL Server Agent job and several correct T-SQL steps should solve your problem.